# Splitting value dataframe over multiple timeslots

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

Would like to spread the values of the 15 minute intervals evenly over the 5 minute intervals. But cannot get it to work. Data is:

```
         Datetime      a   
2018-01-01 00:00:00     6   
2018-01-01 00:15:00     3   
2018-01-01 00:30:00     9
```

Desired output would be:

```
         Datetime         a  
 2018-01-01 00:00:00       2   
 2018-01-11 00:05:00       2  
 2018-01-11 00:10:00       2  
 2018-01-11 00:15:00       1  
 2018-01-11 00:20:00       1  
 2018-01-11 00:25:00       1  
 2018-01-11 00:30:00       3  
 2018-01-11 00:35:00       3  
 2018-01-11 00:40:00       3
```

perhaps unnecessarily, but the value '6' of `00:00:00` in the data is spread over the intervals `00:00:00-00:10:00`

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach:

```
# convert to datetime
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)

# set Datetime as index
df.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True)

# add one extra row
df.loc[df.index.max()+pd.to_timedelta('10min')] = 0

# set_index and resample
s = df.asfreq('5T', fill_value=0)

# transform the 0's to mean:
(s.groupby(s['a'].ne(0)
  .cumsum())
  .transform('mean')
  .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
             Datetime  a
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00  2
1 2018-01-01 00:05:00  2
2 2018-01-01 00:10:00  2
3 2018-01-01 00:15:00  1
4 2018-01-01 00:20:00  1
5 2018-01-01 00:25:00  1
6 2018-01-01 00:30:00  3
7 2018-01-01 00:35:00  3
8 2018-01-01 00:40:00  3
```

Comment: This one works largely, but does not perform the action on the last entry, which can be noted from your output as well

Comment: @KVA Thanks, didn't realize that. We need to add one more row at max time + 10 mins before interpolating. See update.