# Split given time slot into equal interval and fill the time between with avg value

Tags: python, pandas

In my table the hours are from 8am to 6pm daily with values as shown below

```
2/1/21 8:00     54
2/1/21 9:00     54
2/1/21 10:00    54
2/1/21 11:00    54
2/1/21 12:00    54
2/1/21 13:00    45
2/1/21 14:00    45
2/1/21 15:00    45
2/1/21 16:00    0
2/1/21 17:00    0
2/1/21 18:00    0
2/2/21 8:00     54
2/2/21 9:00     54
2/2/21 10:00    54
2/2/21 11:00    54
2/2/21 12:00    54
2/2/21 13:00    54
2/2/21 14:00    0
2/2/21 15:00    0
2/2/21 16:00    0
2/2/21 17:00    0
2/2/21 18:00    0
```

I want the output to look like:

```
2/1/21 8:00 13.5
2/1/21 8:15 13.5
2/1/21 8:30 13.5
2/1/21 8:45 13.5
2/1/21 9:00 0
2/1/21 9:15 0
2/1/21 9:30 0
2/1/21 9:45 0
2/1/21 10:00    13.5
2/1/21 10:15    13.5
...
2/1/21 14:15    11.25
2/1/21 14:30    11.25
2/1/21 14:45    11.25
...
```

I tried this solution: **[Splitting value dataframe over multiple timeslots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468834/splitting-value-dataframe-over-multiple-timeslots)**, but it fills any time gap between dates/timeslots too.
ie it creates time post 6pm too and then it also fills any gaps with the average value - for example:
between 2/1/21 15:00 - 2/2/21:8:00 it averages 45 (15:00 value) as 0.66

Comment: How come `2/1/21 9:00     54`  when split into 15 minutes has zeros? whats the logic?

Comment: `df.asfreq('15min')['value']/4`After this, we can fill NA with `fillna(method='ffill')`.